# Who are your party members and when do you unlock them?

Tags: mario-plus-rabbids-kingdom-battle

You start with Mario, Rabbid Peach, and Rabbid Luigi, but when do you unlock the other characters, and who are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a full listing of the party members and when you unlock them:

- Mario - you start with him
- Rabbid Luigi - you start with him
- Rabbid Peach - you start with her
- Luigi - you get him after completing world 1-5
- Princess Peach - you get her after the world 2 boss is defeated
- Rabbid Mario - you get him after completing world 2-5
- Rabbid Yoshi - you get him after completing world 3-5
- Yoshi - you get him after completing world 4-5